# Nhibernate - Passing more than one parameter into load-collection

Tags: nhibernate

I have collection mapping with sql-query loader in .hbm.xml:

```
`<sql-query name="conpoints">
<load-collection alias="conpoint" role="Substation.ConnectionPoints" />
    SELECT {conpoint.*}
    FROM CONNECTIONPOINT AS conpoint
    WHERE (conpoint.substationID=:Id AND NOT conpoint.ID=:ReceiverConnectionPoint.Id)
</sql-query>`
```

I need to pass both Id and ReceiverConnectionPoint.Id parameter. But NH takes only one of them. How to pass more than one parameter in sql-query?